# How can I constrain generic parameter to have a certain static function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want to have a generic parameter which implement certain static function. As a part of its interface(teh static function) for me it is logical to have such generic parameter constrain, but I cannot find how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Currently I'm fixing such problems by defining NOT static properties which returns static values, which as OOP developer I certainly don't like. This properties are part of some interface and the generic param is constraint to inherit from the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - there's no such thing as constraining a type parameter by static members, unless you count the `new()` constraint which requires a parameterless constructor.

Note that static members can't be part of an interface in the normal C# sense of the word - even though they can obviously be part of the public API of the type.

I've previously blogged about the possibility of ["static interfaces"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces/) in a *future* version of C# (just as a sort of feature request) but it's definitely not available now.

Sometimes the best alternative is to have a *separate* type implementing a normal interface - if you can give us more information about your context, we may be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is not possible to have a constraint in C# like the one you require. I would love to have this feature as well. :)